# Can I make a "global" object to store variables for multiple objects?

Tags: c#, inheritance, persistent

I am creating a graphing application that will display several graphs.  The graphs will need access to some global data and some graph-specific data.  For example, I want the colors consistent, so that would be global, but the specific graphs can have different grid spacing (per graph).

I created a "master object" with set defaults and a derived object with per graph configuration options

```
class GraphMasterObject {
  public Color gridcolor = Color.Red;
}

class GraphObject : GraphMasterObject {
  public int gridSpacing = 10;
}
```

Now, from my understanding, I should be able to do this

```
GraphObject go = new GraphObject();
Color c = go.gridColor;
```

How can I make it so that if I change go.gridColor, it will change across all objects that inherit from GraphMasterObject?  Is this even possible?  If not, what other solutions are possible?   Something like

```
GraphMasterObject gmo = new GraphMasterObject();
gmo.gridColor = Color.Blue;
```

or

```
GraphObject go = new GraphObject();
go.gridColor = Color.Blue;
```

Comment: Why don't you use a static property for gridColor, instead of defining it as a instance property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common approach to have a single object instance shared among many objects is the Singleton Pattern.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

With the Singleton Pattern, any object can request the singleton object and will be returned the same singleton object instance as any other object that requests the singleton object.

That seems like a fine solution in your situation.

One way in C# to implement this pattern is by using a *static* property, e.g.:

```
public class MySingleton
{
    static private MySingleton singleton = null;

    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    static public MySingleton Retrieve
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (singleton == null) singleton = new MySingleton(); // Initialize as needed
            }
            return singleton;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
MySingleton singleton = MySingleton.Retrieve;
```

**UPDATE**

Here's an implementation that is superior to the one above, from the article provided by @Marksl

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> lazy =
        new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

    public static Singleton Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private Singleton()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: if my object inherits from a singleton, will it also be a singleton?  i would like to be able to access data from both the object and the global object transparently

Comment: I dont fully agree with singleton. You can also have a single instance of an object, which is different than singleton actually. and if the value is volatile, every thread should get the latest copy.

Comment: @DarthVader: How exactly is a "single instance of an object" different from the Singleton Pattern?

Comment: @DarthVader: It is if you add locking around the null check and initialization, per the note in my answer.

Comment: @EricJ. no, even `lock` wont make it fully thread safe. and there is a difference between single instance and singleton obviously.

Comment: There's a bug in your code: static public MySingleton Retrieve {...}. Good examples of alternate implementations of the singleton pattern in C#: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx

Comment: @Marksl: Thanks, I have corrected the bug.  Also I went ahead and implemented the lock.  In the article you link, double-checked locking is also not recommended in general for C#.  Not sure if it was Jon Skeet or Eric Lippert, but one of them wrote a good post on that.  Reasoning had to do with the memory barrier issues that plague Java, though I don't recall exactly why it could become an issue for C# as well combined with the fact that the performance gain of double-checked locking almost never matters.

Answer (score 3):

Why use inheritance at all? Why not just have a GlobalGraphSettings object which you pass to all of your Graph objects, then you can just do

```
MyColor = Graph.GlobalSettings.Color;
```

Comment: Yep. Do it with an IoC framework and it's an even sweeter solution. In the mean-time make a factory that sets this relationship up for you. Singleton sucks.