# Prevent a subclass of a singleton class from calling the singleton's constructor

Tags: c#, singleton, subclass

Ok, I have a singleton class `GraphMaster` which contains a number of system-wide values.  I have a subclass `GraphObject : GraphMaster` which has graph specific data.  By subclassing, I can access members of either the global class or subclass.  And by using a singleton class, I can change the global variables anywhere and have them be reflected in all the subclasses.

However, I'm getting stuck because the base class's constructor wants to call the singleton class's constructor, but it can't as it's marked private.

how do I get around this?  Is what I'm trying to do possible?  I went down this path due to responses to this post: [Can I make a "global" object to store variables for multiple objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355150/can-i-make-a-global-object-to-store-variables-for-multiple-objects-in-c)

For example,

```
public class GraphMasterObject {
    private static GraphMasterObject instance;
    private GraphMasterObject() {   }
    }

    public static GraphMasterObject Instance {
        get {
            if (instance == null) instance = new GraphMasterObject();
            return instance;
        }
    }
    public int globalVar=10;
}

public class GraphObject : GraphMasterObject {

   public GraphObject() {
   }

   public int localVar=20;
}
```

I want to be able to do

```
GraphObject go = new GraphObject();
go.globalVar <- this is 10
GraphMasterObject.Instance.globalVar = 20;
go.globalVar <- now this is 20
```

Comment: Singleton class should not be inherited.

Comment: Because the GraphObject is more concret class of GraphMasterObject, by semantic it must be singleton, too.

Comment: I should read Questions correctly, i should read.... Deleted my answer, is not what the op wants.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Ok, I have a singleton class GraphMaster which contains a number of system-wide values. I have a subclass GraphObject : GraphMaster which has graph specific data.

That's a problem to start with. As soon as you have a class which has subclasses, that it by definition *not* a singleton. Someone can add another subclass at any point, and even if you only have one instance of each subclass, you'll have two distinct instances which are compatible with the base class.

You *could* add something in the base class constructor to throw an exception if there's already an instance, but it would be pretty smelly. Fundamentally, singletons are incompatible with subclassing. Rethink your design. (Ideally, avoid the singleton pattern in the first place, but that's another matter...)

Comment: what's the best way to get the functionality i want? Perhaps with reflection magic?

Comment: @reza: As I say, you should redesign. Why do you *want* `GraphObject` to derive from `GraphMasterObject`? Why is that a useful property?

Comment: i want a transparent way to access variables from both the subclass and the base class, but i want the base class's variables to be consistent across all objects and the subclass variables to vary by object.